# Regression model for binary input

Tags: regression, binary-data

I've run into the following problem that I can't seem to find good sources for:

I have a 2d binary matrix, mapping various combinations of a group, in other words, every row is a group with every `1` in the row meaning that a person is present in that group. Columns obviously correspond to the specific people. Given this data, I now want to predict the strength of those groups, which I have in the form of a continuous variable for every group in the dataset. What regression model would work best for such a task?

The problem when researching myself arises with the keyword "Binary" giving me mostly sources either suggesting logistic regression which is used a lot more for binary classification (and while I'm aware it could be implemented in a way to give continuous values, this type of regression seems very wrong for the task) or just in general on sources about binary output.

A good alternative seemed Random Forest Regression at first, however with the team size being relatively small, the data matrix is quite sparse, meaning that if I were to pick random features for every tree, most trees would end up getting built either on zeros only or a fraction of a team. I can imagine barely any trees getting exactly those features that correspond to multiple full teams, in which case, how good of a prediction can the tree even make?

---

Is there something that would work best for this type of task, or is my only option taking five different regression algorithms and just seeing what works the best?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't find anything specific on this topic because *any* regression model would suffice for dealing with binary features. You can use ordinary least squares regression, regularized regression, random forest, $k$NN regression, or any other model. There's [no single best one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_free_lunch_theorem), if there was, we wouldn't have multiple possible models. Different models would work for different datasets. So yes, to pick the model you can either do this empirically, based on their performance, or other properties (e.g. ease of interoperability, etc).

Comment: Well clearly not any regression model, random forest as expected performed horribly - with averaging out and the feature sparsity random forest predicts horribly when it comes to unproportionally strong teams (let's say a team consisting 10 times more people than any other team) or unproportionally weak teams (let's say a team of one person). Your statement is only true if _all_ other models would fail at this regression task equally bad, which I doubt.

Comment: @MantasKandratavičius I didn't say that any regression would perform equally well for your dataset. I said that there's no “the” model for binary features.